# How to create args[] from string in java

Tags: java, command-line, command, command-line-arguments

I need to simulate command line, therefore I need to change string into the args[] in the same way running program with parameters into main method does.

I am using commons cli, but it does not have any parsing method, it does expect array of string already.

I thought, I just use split, but unfortunately, look at this problem :

```
String input = "-command \"This is a long parameter\"";
String args[] = input.split(" ");
//args[0] = -command
//args[1] = "This
//args[2] = is
//etc.
```

If you use this `-command "This is a long parameter"` as parameter to your main method, you get following :

```
//args[0] == -command
//args[1] == This is a long parameter
```

So any suggestion how to do it? The second problem is to find this on google, because every single thread explains whats args[] is, not how to get it from string.

Comment: have you tried input.split("\""); ? As \" is delimiter in your string

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar - well, it can be the right direction, but I have two delimiters - first is `"`, second is ` `(space)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to cut your string.

```
for (String s : "hello \"world this is\" a string"
        .split(" (?=\")|(?<=\")\\s"))
    System.out.println(s);
```

the code above will display:

```
hello 
"world this is"
a string
```